# Django: Get the ID of a clicked button

Tags: django, button, request

I am using django. In my views I want to know which button was pressed.

My **template.html** looks like:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   <button name="{{ post.pk }}" type="submit">{{ post.title }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

I know that in my **views.py** I can check if button x was pressed by just:

```
if '12345' in request.POST:
   # do something
elif '23456' in request.POST:
   #do something else
```

But is there a way to get the primary key without checking every key possible?

I would love something like this:

```
#PSEUDOCODE
post_primary_key = request.POST.get_name()
```

**If my approach is fundamentally bad, I am also open to alternative ways of solving my problem.**

Comment: You can make an array and loop through this.

Answer (score 0):

In your template.html

```
 {% for post in posts %}
    <a href="{% url 'url_name_which directs_to_your_view' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

In your views.py

```
def your_view(request, pk):
    # pk is your primary key, do whatever you want no need to check manually
```

In urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.your_view, name='url_name_which directs_to_your_view'),
```

Comment: If you want to send `POST` request, then please specify will make a little changes. Otherwise if you just want to get the pk of the post which was clicked `(which is your question title)`, then you are good to go.

Comment: Can you tell for ```POST``` request?